# 'Countdown Clock' or 'Countdown Timer'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I want to give a name to a widget my company has developed. It's a countdown widget. You can set any time (Say coming Christmas, Valentine's day) and it'll start a countdown.

Now, I'm peculiar about choosing the name it will be called by. So, which one is better?

> A countdown *clock* **OR**
>  A countdown *timer*

I lean toward *timer* because to me, **clock** is used for measuring the time which is ***forwarding*** and timer we use for something when the time is ***backwarding***.

So, in clock time goes from zero to 'x' number and in timer, it's 'x' number to 'zero'.

Comment: What about just naming it `countdown`?

Answer (score 2):

I think both are fine. You make an interesting point about timers counting down while clocks count up, but it's not always true - both can be used for either direction.

Countdown clock is nicely alliterative.